# Multiply image collection by a number

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I multiply an image collection by a number?

I would like to multiply the image collection by 10 on Line 41.  I have named the variable and stated the variable to be multiplied on that line.  I have also adjusted the code to work with the variable I have defined.

The study area is currently an arbitrary small polygon drawn in GEE.  You can ignore the other study area assets.  The expected output will be in signed int16 form.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e25ab68f0d7756032c7782c6768b56db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map over the `ImageCollection` so you can `multiply()` and cast to int16 each individual `Image` of that collection:

```
var SAR100 = clippedSAR.map(function(image) { 
  return image.multiply(10).toInt16(); 
});
```

Comment: When I use this code, the code in the following object (variables) cannot seem to utilize this SAR100 image collection.  Would you mind trying to help me with this new issue? https://code.earthengine.google.com/a2704f28bfb4596534f255717a8132da